# L2TP/IPSec implementation

Tags: encryption

Recently, I've been given the task of thinking of a way to secure communications (financial transactions), but on lower layers than the network one.

The solution would have a server responsible for key generation with traffic transiting through lower layers to multiple clients (payment terminals, PCs, etc)

After reading some documentation, I came to think that the best way to do so would be the use of L2TP/IPSec, which is basically just tunneling the network layer traffic over the link layer.

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score -2):

IPSec is a good solution in terms of security for tunneling traffic between sites, on the other hand you can choose other alternatives based on VPNs depending on your requirements. My suggestions is to read a bit more about it and check what is the best solution for you.

Comment: "you have options, read more" is a very poor answer. Can you flesh this out at all?